# How to eliminate PropertyPageSchema warnings in VC++ 2010 build with YASM?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, xsd, warnings

I am trying to build Brian Gladman's C code using VS 2010, which uses the modular assembler YASM.  It builds without errors, but there are warnings.  The warning says:

> Warning   1   The element 'ItemGroup' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003' has invalid child element 'PropertyPageSchema' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003'. List of possible elements expected: 'Item, Reference, COMReference, COMFileReference, Xdcmake, Bscmake, ClCompile, ClInclude, Midl, ResourceCompile, PreLinkEvent, CustomBuildStep, Manifest, ProjectConfiguration, NativeReference, ProjectReference, Compile, EmbeddedResource, Content, Page, Resource, ApplicationDefinition, None, BaseApplicationManifest, Folder, Import, Service, WebReferences, WebReferenceUrl, FileAssociation, BootstrapperFile, PublishFile, CodeAnalysisDependentAssemblyPaths, CodeAnalysisDictionary, CodeAnalysisImport, Link, ResourceCompile, PreBuildEvent, PostBuildEvent' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003'.   E:\Visual Studio Projects\Downloaded Projects\BG aes-vs2010-11-01-11\vsyasm.targets 4   6

The beginning of the code that generates the warning is from the file vsyasm.targets.  It contains:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
 <ItemGroup>
   <PropertyPageSchema
     Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)$(MSBuildThisFileName).xml" />
   <AvailableItemName
     Include="YASM">
     <Targets>_YASM</Targets>
   </AvailableItemName>
 </ItemGroup>
 ...
```

The first warning is on the the PropertyPageSchema line.  Does anyone know how to suppress the warnings?  The schema it uses is from 2003.  Is there a more up to date schema somewhere that might eliminate the warnings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had just installed Visual Studio 2010 and installed SP1.  After installing SP1, the warnings were still generated.  But, then Windows Update then provided some updates after that.  It turns out that the updates ended up making the problem go away.  Problem solved.